# Using Maven as build tool for Lua programs

Tags: maven-2, lua

I need a build tool for compiling,testing, reporting and the deployment of Lua programs.

I chose Maven 2 because of our Polarion version supports it.
Unfortunately, I couldn't find any Maven plugins/archetypes for Lua.

As I am a newbie in Maven I want to know whether it is difficult to write a customized Lua plugin for Maven.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hook up the [maven-compiler-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) with any plexus compiler ([reference here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/non-javac-compilers.html)).

So I guess the standard way would be to write a plexus wrapper for the lua compiler using the [Plexus Compiler API](http://plexus.codehaus.org/plexus-components/plexus-compiler/plexus-compilers/index.html)

Comment: +1 for the theoretical resources (although I'm not sure it will be easy in practice).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will have a look on Plexus.